# How to add new Item in dynamodb using same primary and sort keys

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have started working on dynamodb and nodeJs. I want to create an admin panel for adding new item in which primary and sort keys will be same.

For example: ADD URL is abc.com/admin/add/xyz/cdef/123

I have created an api for the same, also I am using 'put' for creating new item however it is replacing the existing one instead of creating new.

Model Code:

```
abc.addData= function(newData, callback){  

var params = {
    TableName: tableconcept,
    Item: newData
}

docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.error("Unable to create post", ". Error JSON:", 
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
   } else {
    // console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       callback(null, data.Items);

        return true;
   }
  });
  }
```

Routes Code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
var data = req.body;

var newData = new Object()
newData.data = data ;

abc.addData(newData, function(err, data){

    if (err){
        return res.status(401).json({
            status:'failed',
            message: "unable to create post"
        });
    }


    return res.status(200).json({
        status:'success',
        message: 'Successfully Created post.'          
    });      

})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The combination partition and sort keys are the primary key.  By definition, you can't have a duplicate.

You could concatenate a timestamp onto the end of the sort key in order to make each unique.

Then when retrieving,  a query using a "Sort key starts with" would return all the records.